# Treatment for mild Tourette syndrome

Tags: neurology, symptoms, treatment-options, muscle-tremor-twitch, tourette-syndrome

I have a friend who has had Tourette syndrome since he was a child. He is 26 now, the Tourette is mild, involving shoulder twitching.

Is there any treatment that bring the syndrome to a negligible/manageable level without taking any medication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current treatments for Tourette syndrome (drugs like dopamine receptor antagonists, which are the reference treatment, excepted) include:

- Psychotherapy/behaviour therapy/habit training
- Deep brain stimulation (for severe cases, so not really applicable here)
- Transcranial magnetic stimulation
- Biofeedback

[Review of the research progresses in Tourette syndrome (2014)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4602330/)

Comment: so for this case, the first one, i.e., behavior threapy is applicable right?

Comment: @Rishika It's applicable indeed and in this specific case would probably be the best choice

Comment: what is the maximum scope of improvement in this case?

Comment: @Rishika [This study on habit reversal](www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26583455) finds there is "an improvement in terms of reduced tics and improved global functioning in both groups, without significant changes in terms of Quality of Life"

Comment: [This one is a detailed review on behaviour therapy](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40474-015-0063-5) and concludes "professional organizations recommend behavior therapy as a first-line intervention for individuals with mild-to-moderate tic severity", with significant results in terms of tic severity (percentage of reduction varying from 10-35%). Sorry for the double comment, was unaware of the 5-min rule.